# How to stop an async function

Tags: python

I want to find a way to stop the call of a function

Currently I found this method in function

```
from func_timeout import func_set_timeout

########  is ok #########
@func_set_timeout(timeout=2)
def is_ok_request():
    import time
    time.sleep(10)

is_ok_request()
```

But currently I can't stop the call in an async function

```
def down_file():
    '''eg. this a third-party modules  '''
    time.sleep(100000)

async def timeout_func():
    '''down a file times out 10s to exit'''
    print("start connection mysql")
    down_file()
    print("end connection mysql")
    
async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(timeout_func(),timeout=1)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')


asyncio.run(main())
```

help

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems:

1. Don't call `time.sleep()` in async progams! Always await `asyncio.sleep()` instead.
2. The timeout of `asyncio.wait` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait)) is the time when to stop waiting. It does not cancel anything. Use `asyncio.wait_for` ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait_for)) instead. It generates a `TimeoutError` that should be handled.

Not an error, but `loop.run_until_complete()` is not the recommended way to run an async program. Use `asyncio.run()` as the entry-point, it is like `run_until_complete` with a cleanup afterward.

Another issue: `task = my_request()`. It is not a task, it is a coroutine. In asyncio, the term *task* has a fixed meaning ([link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks)). The `wait` documentation warns, that it expects tasks and will not accept coroutines in future versions.

The code in its simplest form (actually, it is almost the same as an example in the linked docs):

```
import asyncio
import time

async def my_request():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

async def main():
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(my_request(), timeout=1)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks I want to implement a general coroutine function. This coroutine function can stop executing some functions that are too long. Is there a module that can be like func_timeout. (please see my latest code)